# Composition of paths in Hatcher

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have just started reading Hatcher's Algebraic Topology. During the section on the fundamental group he defines the composition of two paths with $f(1) = g(0)$ as $$f \circ g(s) = \begin{cases} f(2s),&0\leq s \leq 1/2\\g(2s-1),&1/2\leq s \leq 1 \end{cases}$$
However, from my experience with functions we always compose backwards, since $f$ is the first path and $g$ begins where $f$ ends, is it not out of convention of a regular composition? It also seems that he uses a square instead of a circle for composition. My worry is that if I follow this convention I will get myself confused when it comes to solving problems because I am so used to viewing function composition backwards. I guess my question is, is there any reason for creating this new convention?

Comment: This isn’t function composition.

Comment: @IttayWeiss Is a path not a function?

Comment: The word “composition” as it’s used here is just a name chosen by Hatcher to define an operation on paths. It has nothing to do with function composition. One could just as well have called this “concatenation” of paths, or any other word you like.

Comment: This not function composition.  It is path concatenation.  That said, while Hatcher's use is somewhat idiosyncratic, he defines the term.  As the caterpillar says "When I use a word... it means just what I choose it to mean."

Comment: @jamesmartini paths are functions, yes. But that doesn't guarantee that path composition is function composition, which indeed it cannot be. if $f\colon I\to X$ and $g\colon I\to X$, there is no way to compose $f$ and $g$ as functions since the codomain of one is not the domain of the other (except in the case that the space $X$ happens to be the unit interval $I$). So this is a different operation than function composition, even if its name is confusingly similar.

Comment: The (downloadable) book "Categories and groupoids" by P.J. Higgins uses the algebraists' convention for functions with $(x)f$ meaning the value of the function $f$ on $x$. so we get $(x)(fg)=((x)f)g$.  This convention  is not so easy to use in analysis or calculus!